# Class<? implements X>: How can I define a variable that is an instance of this

Tags: java, class, casting, hierarchy, entities

I have a lot of different classes.

Some implement X. Other's don't.

I now need to have access to one specific instance of such a class implementing X, and also want to avoid many unnecessary casts.

I can't simply say `MyClass instance;`, for reasons of type safety.

I can't use `X instance` either, because I do need access to the methods of the class.

I can't have a `OtherClass extends MyClass implements X` either, because most of my classes are already extending MyClass, but I don't want all of my subclasses to implement X.

Thus, I'm searching for a way to define a variable type in a way that something like this could be written:
`MyClass<? implements X>`, similarly to the way classes can be written `Class<? implements X>`

I know that this exact syntax is impossible, due to my classes not being generic classes, but is there another way of doing it?

To clarify why I need it, in case some of you might suggest a better solution:

I have a lot of different Entities. Each Entity Type gets its own class.
However, the classes are organized as a tree: On top you have the `Entity`, and then it branches further and further out. I want a few of these entities to implement my interface X though (`IControllable` in my case).

In my main class, I am referencing one specific instance of an Entity, which is the one that is being controlled by my system. However: That entity can only be controlled if it implements IControllable.

Also: I need to pass that reference to some functions, which accept an `Entity` object. Since `X`, or `IControllable`, is implemented by an Entity and not the other way around, there's no way for me to pass it without some weird and unsafe casts.

Any solutions? Thanks!

Edit, to clarify: Yes, I CAN *definitely*  solve the problems with casts, *however* these are ugly and I'm looking for a better design.

Comment: "because I do need access to the methods of the class." Then your best option is `MyClass instance`. What "reasons of clarity" mean you can't do this?

Comment: @AndyTurner Imagine someone else would join the codebase. (S)he may make the error of assigning an MyClass instance that doesnt implement X to the variable instance, which would result in errors. Additionally, I ALSO need access to methods from X.

Comment: Ah, so nothing to do with clarity at all? :) (Clarity => readability; you're talking about type safety)

Comment: @AndyTurner Riight, sorry, mixed those two up!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic with multiple bounds:

```
<T extends MyClass & X> void someFunction(T t){
}
```

This would enforce that parameters of `someFunction` would be a subtype of both `MyClass` and `X` and allows you to access members of both `MyClass` and `X`.